# OpenCV VideoCapture() on Ubuntu 17.04 not working

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, webcam, video-capture

I'm trying to use OpenCV's cv2 python bindings on Ubuntu 17.04 and I can't seem to get VideoCapture to work properly. I'm doing a test with the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
plt.ion()
while True:
    ret,image = cap.read()
    print(image)
    print(cap)
    im = np.array(image, dtype=float)
    plt.imshow(im)
    plt.pause(0.0005)
    plt.show()
```

and the result is

```
None
<VideoCapture 0x7f272f87adb0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cam.py", line 15, in <module>
    plt.imshow(im)
  File "/home/daniele/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3157, in imshow
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/daniele/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1898, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/daniele/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5124, in imshow
    im.set_data(X)
  File "/home/daniele/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 600, in set_data
    raise TypeError("Invalid dimensions for image data")
TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data
```

and no window with video from webcam is opened.

If I don't use `im = np.array(image, dtype=float)` the error is the same but `TypeError: Image data can not convert to float`
I have checked that my webcam is 0 in my system and I tryed it with 'Cheese' and it works. 
I have installed Opencv by `pip3 install opencv-python`

Comment: Can you use some other app to open webcam? What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV already has some in-built utils for displaying images in a window using `cv2.imshow()`, using the OpenCV API you wont need to convert the image to `np.array()`. See if the following code works:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret,image = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("window", image)
    # Set the window delay time in milliseconds.
    cv2.waitkey(300)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible though to show the image in another way than the one provided by `cv2`?

Comment: this is not the problem, and as described in opencv site: [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python) ' MacOS and Linux wheels have currently some limitations:

video related functionality is not supported (not compiled with FFmpeg)
for example cv2.imshow() will not work (not compiled with GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support) '. So I resolved using pyplot. Anyway in my macbook the script works fine.

Comment: How have you installed OpenCV ?

Comment: Just found out that with older versions of opencv like 3.1.0 everything works fine. I successfully installed it on Ubuntu but I can't on OSX.

Comment: I have installed compiling the source code of opencv-3.0.1